# Redirect Url for gocardless in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was trying to implement gocardless in my laravel project.

First i want to create a token via redirect flows.
but the parameters which will give when calling redirect flows via curl contains a success_redirect_url.
but it returns an error like,

```
    Array
  (
[error] => Array
    (
        [message] => Validation failed
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [field] => success_redirect_url
                        [message] => must be HTTP or HTTPS
                        [request_pointer] => /redirect_flows/success_redirect_url
                    )

            )

        [documentation_url] => https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference#validation_failed
        [type] => validation_failed
        [request_id] => 8e873944-c3e2-4838-8666-d7683d0db6a6
        [code] => 422
    )

     )
```

my ajax controller is ,

```
      $param_array = array(
                  "redirect_flows" => array(
                   "description" => $compdata[0]['pack'],
                   "session_token" => $session_token,
                   "success_redirect_url" => '/gocardless_calculation/'
                                           )
                          );
```

and my route is,

```
 Route::post('/gocardless_calculation', '\App\Http\Controllers\tunnel\controller@setupgocardless')->name('gocardless_calculation');
```

How to give a success redirect url in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return redirect with message.

```
return redirect('route.name')->with('success', 'Added Successfully!');
```

And in view get values from Session

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {!! \Session::get('success') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```